# Magento bundle product original price

Tags: php, magento

How I could get bundle product original price when price is set to dynamic (price excluding special - when is setup)?

I'm trying like this:

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol().number_format($_product->getPrice(),2) ?>
```

But it works only for fixed price, if price is dynamic it show 0.00

Best would be method that will work for both prices: fixed and dynamic

Answer (score 1):

See the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml

```
$_product     = $this->getProduct();
$_priceModel  = $_product->getPriceModel();

list($_minimalPriceTax, $_maximalPriceTax) = $_priceModel->getTotalPrices($_product, null, null, false);
list($_minimalPriceInclTax, $_maximalPriceInclTax) = $_priceModel->getTotalPrices($_product, null, true, false);
```

string ~128 - formatted the bundle price with dynamic type.

```
<?php if ($_minimalPriceTax <> $_maximalPriceTax): ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you bundle product dynamic price including tax    `Mage::getModel('bundle/product_price')->getTotalPrices($_product,'max',1);`

This will give you bundle product dynamic price excluding tax `Mage::getModel('bundle/product_price')->getTotalPrices($_product,'max',0);`

Just pass your product object correctly.